# Implementing disk quota for MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, disk-space

I want my Linux MariaDB database to have disk quota implemented.
How can I achieve this these days?

I have found some tools but they are for MySQL, don't know if they are supposed to work on MariaDB.

Comment: have a look at `cf-mysql-quota-enforcer` for an example https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-mysql-release/tree/b68fc84488bf50768031310bfe6d8113a96b9e5b/src/quota-enforcer there is no out-of-the-box solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running this script in `cron`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

/*
 * MySQL quota script
 * written by Sebastian Marsching
 * updated by Daniel Santos
 *
 */

/*
 *  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 *  Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */


/*
 * Create table for quota data with the following statement:
 *
 * CREATE TABLE `quota` (`db` CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 * `limit` BIGINT NOT NULL,
 * `exceeded` ENUM('Y','N') DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
 * PRIMARY KEY (`db`), UNIQUE (`db`));
 *
 * The field 'db' stores the information for which database
 * you want to limit the size.
 * The field 'limit' is the size limit in bytes.
 * The field 'exceeded' is only used internally and must be
 * initialized with 'N'.
 */

/*
 * Settings
 */

$mysql_host  = 'localhost';
$mysql_user  = 'root'; // Do NOT change, root-access is required
$mysql_pass  = '';
$mysql_db    = 'quotadb'; // Not the DB to check, but the db with the quota table
$mysql_table = 'quota';

/*
 * Do NOT change anything below
 */

$debug = 0;

// Connect to MySQL Server

$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection to MySQL-server failed!";
    exit;
}


// Check quota for each entry in quota table

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_table;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $quota_db = $row['db'];
    $quota_limit = $row['limit'];
    $quota_exceeded = ($row['exceeded']=='Y') ? 1 : 0;

    if ($debug) {
        echo "Checking quota for '$quota_db'...\n";
    }

    $qsql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM $quota_db;";
    $qresult = mysqli_query($con, $qsql);

    if ($debug) {
        echo "SQL-query is \"$qsql\"\n";
    }

    $quota_size = 0;

    while ($qrow = mysqli_fetch_array($qresult)) {
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Result of query:\n";
            var_dump($qrow);
        }
        $quota_size += $qrow['Data_length'] + $qrow['Index_length'];
    }

    if ($debug) {
        echo "Size is $quota_size bytes, limit is $quota_limit bytes\n";
    }

    if ($debug && $quota_exceeded) {
        echo "Quota is marked as exceeded.\n";
    }
    if ($debug && !$quota_exceeded) {
        echo "Quota is not marked as exceeded.\n";
    }

    if (($quota_size > $quota_limit) && !$quota_exceeded) {
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Locking database...\n";
        }
        // Save in quota table
        $usql = "UPDATE $mysql_table SET exceeded='Y' WHERE db='$quota_db';";
        mysqli_query($con, $usql);
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Querying: $usql\n";
        }
        // Dismiss CREATE and INSERT privilege for database
        mysqli_select_db($con, 'mysql');
        $usql = "UPDATE db SET Insert_priv='N', Create_priv='N' WHERE db='$quota_db';";
        mysqli_query($con, $usql);
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Querying: $usql\n";
        }
        mysqli_select_db($con, $mysql_db);
    }

    if (($quota_size <= $quota_limit) && $quota_exceeded) {
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Unlocking database...\n";
        }
        // Save in quota table
        $usql = "UPDATE $mysql_table SET exceeded='N' WHERE db='$quota_db';";
        mysqli_query($con, $usql);
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Querying: $usql\n";
        }
        // Grant CREATE and INSERT privilege for database
        mysqli_select_db($con, 'mysql');
        $usql = "UPDATE db SET Insert_priv='Y', Create_priv='Y' WHERE db='$quota_db';";
        mysqli_query($con, $usql);
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Querying: $usql\n";
        }
        mysqli_select_db($con, $mysql_db);
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You first need to put your mariadb `root` password in the script.
You then need to create a database named `quotadb` and add this table to it:

`` CREATE TABLE `quota` (`db` CHAR(64) NOT NULL, `limit` BIGINT NOT NULL, `exceeded` ENUM('Y','N') DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`db`), UNIQUE (`db`)); ``

In this table you will add the values of the database you want quota for and the value for the size of the quota (in bytes).

Execute this script on `cron` and you are good to go

Comment: Instead of implementing this as a cron job, you could use a MariaDB [event](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-event/). And another thing that may or may not be useful in relation to this is the [MariaDB 10.3 `DISKS` plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-disks-table/).

Comment: Can you post an howto answer using events and disk plugin?

Comment: @dbdemon the DISKS plugin seems not to offer quota feature. It's only for monitoring inside DB the Linux devices. Because most DBA don't have access to system level monitoring.

Comment: @FydorGlebov Yes, I only mentioned it as a source of related, potentially useful info if additional features were to be added to the program. E.g. to sanity-check quotas so they don't exceed available disk space.

Comment: Re: the `UPDATE db ...` statement: It would be better to use `GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements. It's not advisable to write directly to this table, although I'm sure it works fine in a lot of cases. Galera Cluster is one use-case where it probably doesn't work, unless you turn on the experimental MyISAM support.

Comment: @dbdemon, what would a `GRANT` or `REVOKE` command look like in this case? I can update the script

Comment: I think something like: GRANT: For each record in the mysql.db table with Db = $quota_db, Insert_priv = 'N' or Create_priv='N', get the  Host, User values and run: `GRANT INSERT, CREATE ON $quota_db.* TO $user@$host`. REVOKE: For each record in the mysql.db table with Db = $quota_db, Insert_priv = 'Y' or Create_priv='Y', get the  Host, User values and run: `REVOKE INSERT, CREATE ON $quota_db.* FROM $user@$host`.

Comment: Thank you @dbdemon . Since there may be different databases for different users I won't add the `GRANT` and `REVOKE` commands